# Openfire MultiUser Chat - Scalability

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack, multiuserchat

I created a sample program that joins a multi user chat room in Openfire Server.

I changed the "Maximum Room Occupants" of multi user chat room to "unlimited".

On joining around 850 user in a multi user chat room, I am getting the following exception

```
org.jivesoftware.openfire.session.LocalSession - Internal server error
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.NIOConnection.deliver(NIOConnection.java:356)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.session.LocalClientSession.deliver(LocalClientSession.java:857)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.session.LocalSession.process(LocalSession.java:289)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.muc.spi.LocalMUCRole.send(LocalMUCRole.java:263)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.muc.spi.LocalMUCRoom.broadcast(LocalMUCRoom.java:1155)....
```

CPU Usage is also increasing to 100% at this time.

Please advice me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to me you should go for high configured server.That have good RAM and Processor. So, it handled more users in multi-chat.

Just talk once in openfire community with moderators.Take advice from them.
They will give you best solution. 
[here](https://www.igniterealtime.org/support/group_chat.jsp) you can go.

Thank You hope this will help you.